# wp_validate_auth_cookie interfering on Woocommerce API

Tags: wordpress, authentication, woocommerce

I'm with some strange issue. Everything about generating and validating auth_cookies **is working fine**, but when I validate a cookie anywhere using [wp_validate_auth_cookie](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_validate_auth_cookie/), the Woocommerce API doesn't work fine anymore.

For example, the orders endpoint:

```js
const settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/orders?consumer_key=ck_...&consumer_secret=cs_...&customer=10&page=1&per_page=40",
  "method": "GET",
  "headers": {
    "cache-control": "no-cache"
  }
};

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response); // It works!
});
```

It works perfectly, in this way I can get all orders from customer with ID 10 with no problem. But if I add any validation using [wp_validate_auth_cookie](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_validate_auth_cookie/), the REST API works as Unauthorized.

Take a look at a simple validation cookie on **init** hook, which takes the cookie from `$_GET`:

```php
add_action('init', 'validate_cookies');

function validate_cookies(){
    $cookie = $_GET['cookie'];
    $user_id = wp_validate_auth_cookie($cookie, 'logged_in');
    if (!$user_id) {
      die;
    }
}
```

As you can see, if there's an invalid cookie, the script will die. Using a valid cookie (generated with [wp_generate_auth_cookie](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_generate_auth_cookie/)), the `$user_id` is returned correctly, but the same first call with a cookie on the query string to the orders endpoint will now fail as Unauthorized:

```
https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/orders?consumer_key=ck_...&consumer_secret=cs_...&customer=10&page=1&per_page=40&cookie=email@...
```

I thought that `wp_validate_auth_cookie` could be authenticating the user automatically, but adding `wp_get_current_user` after validating the cookie, it will still return the ID from the API key owner, as it should be.

Can someone help me understand why it happens?

Answer (score 0):

As the second parameter of the [**`wp_validate_auth_cookie`**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_validate_auth_cookie/) function you are using `logged_in`.

Make sure you set the same value as the **third parameter** of the [**`wp_generate_auth_cookie`**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_generate_auth_cookie/) function.

> By default the value is `auth`.

In your case, try replacing:

```
$user_id = wp_validate_auth_cookie($cookie, 'logged_in');
```

with:

```
$user_id = wp_validate_auth_cookie($cookie, 'auth');
```

Comment: The problem isn't the validation, which is working fine. The issue is, when I validate it, the Woocommerce API stops working.

Comment: What error is returned to you? Did you also check the log file?

Comment: The error is the same like I'm not using the valid credentials `woocommerce_rest_cannot_view`, because of that I think that `wp_validate_auth_cookie` is in some way also logging-in the user.

Comment: I don't know how to help you further, sorry.